# Writing BSONBinary to MongoDB fails with reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to save data into the database of a binary type.
The call is:

```
val query = BSONDocument("_id" -> binId)
val update = BSONDocument(
  "$inc" -> BSONDocument(
    "fieldA" -> 1L
  ))

coll.update(query, update, GetLastError(), upsert = true)
```

where

```
binId = BSONBinary(id, UuidSubtype):
```

I get exception from reactivemongo that looks in log like this:

```
ERROR akka.remote.EndpointWriter ClusterSystem-akka.acto
r.default-dispatcher-3 - Transient association error (association remains live)
java.io.NotSerializableException: reactivemongo.bson.buffer.ArrayReadableBuffer
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
```

Any hints would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, this was the message not from the reactivemongo, but from akka that was preceeding the database transaction. Basically it was Akka that was not able to serialize BSONBinary to send over the network.